# using aimated gifs in a slider

Tags: jquery, carousel

I am using the slider http://jacksbox.de/stuff/jquery-fractionslider/ and want to have some animated gifs within the slides.  I need the gifs to be loaded in when the slide is active as they only play once (not looping)

any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

you could place placeholder `<img src="blank.gif" />` and preload the gifs, when the slide is shown you would swap the `src` attribute